# Python multiprocessing Pool.map() infinite loop issue

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

I applied Pool.map() function to my user_defined function which loads data from DB and it does not work well. **It keeps infinite loop.**

**There is no problem importing data from DB separately in each jupyter notebook without using 'pool.map()'.** **Do you know what's the difference between separately loading from DB and loading with map() at once?**

If I can know the difference between the two processes, I think I can find a clue to solving the problem of looping and not stopping.

When I use not my user_defined function but use 'sum()' or any other basic functions, I could realize that parallel processing using 'pool.map()' was executed well.

```
def parallelized():
  with Pool(processes = 8) as pool:
      if __name__ == '__main__':
          df = pool.map(minc, yms)
      pool.close()
      pool.join()
return df

parallelized()


yms = ['201901','201902','201903','201904','201905','201906','201907','201908','201909','201910','201911','201912','201801','201802','201803','201804','201805','201806','201807','201808','201809','201810','201811','201812']

def minc(ym):
  print('MINC %s %s\n' %(ym, str(datetime.datetime.now())))
  print("value %s is in PID : %s \n" % (ym, os.getpid()))
  t = datetime.datetime.now()

  minc1 = pd.read_sql("""
  select substring(MINC_IN_YM,1,4) as YEAR,substring(MINC_IN_YM,5,2) as 
  MONTH,
  MINC_VNDCD as 'FROM', 
  MINC_BRNCD+''+MINC_BRNCD_WHS as 'TO', 
  MINC_PTNO as PTNO,
  count(MINC_INSP_NO) as NROWS,
  sum(MINC_OKQTY) as TOTAL_QUANTITY,
  sum(MINC_AV_PRICE*MINC_OKQTY)  as TOTAL_DOLLARS 
  from dwadm.W_MINC
  where MINC_INC_INF in ('RN','CN')
  and MINC_ACCID in  ('A', 'G', 'V')
  and MINC_IN_YM ='%s'
  and substring(MINC_BRNCD, 1, 1) not in ('S','C')
  GROUP BY YEAR,MONTH, MINC_BRNCD,MINC_BRNCD_WHS,MINC_VNDCD, MINC_PTNO
  """ % ym , conn)

  print(' MINC ends %s1 %s %s\n' %(ym, 
  str(datetime.datetime.now()),str(datetime.datetime.now()-t)))

  return minc1
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: @OneLiner I posted my code

Comment: I am suspicious of any use of multiprocessing in jupyter notebook. I think they might not be compatible. Try running the code in the terminal instead.

Comment: @DanD. I'll try. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `if __name__ == '__main__':` at the top level around the `parallelized()` call.

Comment: Thx. But I changed that part just now and It doesn't seem to solve the problem. :(